# 'rake aborted! cannot load such file -- rack' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, redmine

Im installing Redmine v2.2.3 on CentOS v5.6. I have ruby v1.9.3p385 installed. When i do `rake generate_secret_token` or `bundle exec rake generate_secret_token` i get the error `'rake aborted! cannot load such file -- rack'`. The complete trace is as follows

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rack
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch.rb:35:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/railtie.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/railtie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails.rb:14:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/projects/redmine/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/mnt/projects/redmine/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/projects/redmine/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/mnt/projects/redmine/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

The rack gem is already installed. When i do `bundle show rack` i get

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rack-1.4.5
```

Please Help.
Thank You.

Comment: have you tried `require './rack'`, instead of just `require 'rack'`?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the whole bundle and re-bundled the project.